Trouble Confirming Solana Transactions on Mainnet: Timeout and Blockheight Exceeded Errors
I'm developing a Solana application and encountering issues when trying to confirm transactions on the Mainnet. While everything worked as expected on Devnet, transitioning to Mainnet has led to repeated failures with specific error messages indicating timeouts and block height exceedances.
Backend Code:
async function prepareTransferTransaction(userWalletPublicKey, amount, feePayerPublicKey) {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
    const secretKeyUint8Array = await accessSecretVersion("solana");
    const gameWalletKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKeyUint8Array);
    const tokenMintAddress = "";
    const recipientPublicKey = new PublicKey(userWalletPublicKey);

    const recipientTokenAccount = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        gameWalletKeypair,
        new PublicKey(tokenMintAddress),
        recipientPublicKey,
        true
    );

    const sourceTokenAccount = new PublicKey("");
    const tokenDecimals = 2;
    const transferAmount = amount * Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals);
    const transferInstruction = splToken.createTransferInstruction(
        sourceTokenAccount,
        recipientTokenAccount.address,
        gameWalletKeypair.publicKey,
        transferAmount,
        [],
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    let transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);
    transaction.feePayer = new PublicKey(feePayerPublicKey);
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
    transaction.partialSign(gameWalletKeypair);

    const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
        requireAllSignatures: false,
        verifySignatures: false
    });

    return serializedTransaction.toString("base64");
}


This is part of the api that does some additional verifications before calling prepareTransferTransaction
 // Generate the transaction to be sent to the frontend
        const transactionBase64 = await prepareTransferTransaction(userWallet, userTokens, feePayerPublicKey);

        // Send the transaction to the frontend first to minimize delay
        res.status(200).send({
            transaction: transactionBase64,
        });

Frontend Code:
const handleClaimTokens = async () => {
    const base64Transaction = await fetchTransactionData();
    if (!base64Transaction) {
        console.warn("Transaction data is undefined. Stopping function.");
        return;
    }

    const transactionBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Transaction, "base64");
    const transaction = Transaction.from(transactionBuffer);
    const signedTransaction = await signTransaction(transaction);

    const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize(), {
        skipPreflight: true,
    });

    console.log("Transaction signature:", signature);

    try {
        const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "confirmed");
        console.log("Transaction confirmation:", confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error claiming tokens:", error);
    }
};


For the first version of the code I'm getting these errors:
TransactionExpiredTimeoutError: Transaction was not confirmed in 30.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed.
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature has expired: block height exceeded.
I've tried adding a priority fee to ensure faster processing and adjusted the confirmation logic to wait based on the latest blockhash, but I'm still encountering the following errors:
  const handleClaimTokens = async () => {
    try {
      const base64Transaction = await fetchTransactionData();
      if (!base64Transaction) {
        console.warn("Transaction data is undefined. Stopping function.");
        return;
      }

      const transactionBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Transaction, "base64");
      const transaction = Transaction.from(transactionBuffer);

      // Assuming `signTransaction` is a function that signs the transaction with the user's wallet
      const signedTransaction = await signTransaction(transaction);

      // Optional: Add a priority fee to the transaction
      const priorityFeeInstruction = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
        microLamports: 15000, // Set this to an appropriate value based on current network conditions
      });
      transaction.add(priorityFeeInstruction);

      const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize(), {
        skipPreflight: true,
      });
      console.log("Transaction signature:", signature);

      // Confirm the transaction based on the latest blockhash
      const block = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
      const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(
        {
          signature,
          ...block,
        },
        "confirmed",
      );

      if (confirmation.value.err) {
        throw new Error(confirmation.value.err.toString());
      }

      console.log("Transaction confirmation:", confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error claiming tokens:", error);
      if (error.message.includes("User rejected the request")) {
        console.warn("Transaction signing was rejected by the user.");
      } else {
        console.error("Error during transaction signing:", error);
      }
    }
  };

but getting these errors:
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5KGCoEhJPoGB114BJLYeEWmjss4MgsRkZqa9xJaxjprLCkYMYpjafESPySgpKwKFio1auPMpBP5dN3C93A4KPzBN has expired: block height exceeded. at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5KGCoEhJPoGB114BJLYeEWmjss4MgsRkZqa9xJaxjprLCkYMYpjafESPySgpKwKFio1auPMpBP5dN3C93A4KPzBN has expired: block height exceeded. at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
